# R - Chorddiag : Why transposing the matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, transpose, chord-diagram

Why have I to transpose my origin-destination matrix to use the chorddiag package, please ?

Unfortunately, I can't add any pictures to illustrate the post but if I don't transpose the matrix, the flow direction from my bipartite chord diagram comes from the destination and goes to the origin. What it makes no-sense. The flow direction must go from the origin to the destination.
I hope to be clear enough.

Is it any mathematical reason or is it just like this because of the package ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: can you give a little more detail please? Maybe an example? My initial answer (without looking at anything) would be "because that's the way the package authors designed it" ... ??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok no problem ! I'll do it right now !